# Scala: Get Image as bytes array from an external URL?

Tags: scala

I want to get an image as bytes array from an external URL in Scala. What's the way to do the same?

```
val url = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/jUoaTIlBn5ibfQcND2n5OMD6Z7xoqNj-ShHlFR6QuLffLXD5pS8V2eNg1rGlrsRrnDkoQ28O8UHzqzBQKAGY4l1CS2NQSq2SkRScK6FOjl82jppyohK-"
```

```
def getImageFromUrlInBytes = (url:String):Array[Bytes] = ???
```

Comment: What have you tried? Why it didn't work? Anyways, check `Source`: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/io/Source.html or https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html

Comment: You can try https://github.com/com-lihaoyi/requests-scala, a python's requests like lib for scala.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Scala 2.13+ and Java 9+:

```
  def getImageFromUrlInBytes(urlString: String): Array[Byte] = {
    Using.resource(new URL(urlString).openStream()) { in =>
      in.readAllBytes()
    }
  }
```

`InputStream.readAllBytes` is a useful method of Java 9+.